# Can't use floats in WebGL GLSL shader constant #if expression?

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

In WebGL GLSL, I'm trying to do something like:

```
#if (2.0 > 3.0)
    // something
#endif
```

But this errors with:

> ERROR: 0:21: 'syntax error' : invalid expression
>   ERROR: 0:21: '2.0' : unexpected token after conditional expression

[The 1.0 spec says](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf):

> A *constant expression* is one of
>
> • a literal value (e.g., 5 or **true**)

Aren't floats literal values?

Similarly, I'm also not sure why this doesn't work, since it's a `const` variable, using a constant expression for the value:

```
const vec3 x = vec3(1.0);
...
#if (x.x > 1.0)
#endif
```

> ERROR: 0:21: 'x' : unexpected token after conditional expression
>
> ERROR: 0:21: 'syntax error' : invalid expression
>
> ERROR: 0:21: '.' : unexpected token after conditional expression

Comment: the *pre*processor doesn't know `x` because its executed before your actual shader code is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, from the same document in the Preprocessor section, it says:

> Expressions following #if and #elif are restricted to expressions operating on literal integer constants, plus identifiers consumed by the defined operator.

Which is why floats, `length()` etc don't work.